I've been offered to join a company with a base salary plus shares but i have no experience in this. Can someone please help?
I've been offered to join a small company with a base salary plus share and the current owners are willing to negotiate the terms. Company is a pty ltd (Australian).
Knowing the above, can someone please advise me what type of contract suit me best as I would like to achive the below:

Exit protection: if i leave the company there will be nothing while if the company get rid of me payout will be 100% share at certain value.
Salary protection: company will no be able to review salary downwards unless agreed
Option of increase shares yearly when agreed objectives are met

Also i would like to know the below:

How can i protect myself in case of the company fail (have the share under a trust?)
How the future value of the share is calculated? (Example if current sales rev is 3mil and future projection will be 30mil what would be the payout? if payout doesn't depend on sales revenue how does it work?)
Any other thing that you can share on the matter that i haven't incorporated
What type of professional should i engage to review the contract?

Regards

There's no advice on the terms you want in your employment - either the company will accept them, or it won't. There's nothing you can do to "force" them to accept your terms.  And putting too many protections for you in place could be a negative way to start the employment relationship.  I have no idea how much leverage you have in this negotiation to know if there's any way they would accept any of these terms.
As far as the equity compensation goes:

How can I protect myself in case of the company fail (have the share under a trust?)

If there are publicly traded options on the company (which there probably aren't given your description) then you could buy puts to guarantee that you can sell them at a certain price by a certain date. But that protection is not free. You will have to pay a premium for the options.
If it is privately traded, there's not much you can do unless you can convince the company to guarantee a sales price (which they probably won't).
Putting them in a trust won't protect the value at all.

How the future value of the share is calculated?

There are many ways to value a stock, but they require a lot of knowledge and guessing about the future performance of the company. There's no way to predict how much the stock will be worth.  In the end, it's worth whatever someone is willing to pay you for it.
The bottom line is relying on equity compensation is a big risk. If you can live on just the salary, then it may be a risk that you want to take. The good news is that the stock will never cost you anything - the worst that can happen is the stock becomes worthless. But it could result in a huge payoff that you could never get on your salary alone. It's up to you whether you want to take that risk or not.
